# Whats wrong in my python dictionary looping code?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of currencies:

{'USD': 1.316, 'GBP': 0.812, 'LTL': 3.4528}

and I need the output to be:

{'LTL': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316},

'GBP': {'LTL': 3.4528, 'USD': 1.316},

'USD': {'LTL': 3.4528, 'GBP': 0.812},

'EUR': {'LTL': 3.4528, 'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316}}

My code is here:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def currency(dictionary):

    new_dictionary = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_dictionary[key] = dictionary
        new_dictionary['EUR'] = dictionary
    print(new_dictionary)

    for k, v in new_dictionary.items():
        copy = deepcopy(v)
        for i, j in copy.items():
            if k in i:
                del v[i]
    return new_dictionary

print(currency({'USD': 1.316, 'GBP': 0.812, 'LTL': 3.4528}))
```

But I get empty values and when I try like this, it works:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def currency(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        copy = deepcopy(value)
        for i, j in copy.items():
            if key in i:
                del value[i]

    return dictionary

print(currency({'GBP': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316, 'LTL': 3.4528},     'USD': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316, 'LTL': 3.4528},'LTL': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316, 'LTL': 3.4528},'EUR': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316, 'LTL': 3.4528}}))
```

I don't understand where's the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [8]: res = {}

In [14]: for k, v in ccy.items():
   ....:     tdict=deepcopy(ccy)
   ....:     tdict.pop(k)
   ....:     res[k]=tdict
   ....:

In [15]: res
Out[15]:
{'GBP': {'LTL': 3.4528, 'USD': 1.316},
 'LTL': {'GBP': 0.812, 'USD': 1.316},
 'USD': {'GBP': 0.812, 'LTL': 3.4528}}
```